# Persisting Data Between MVVM View Changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an application which contains a hierarchy of View/Viewmodels.

ViewModelBase contains two ViewModels

```
private AViewModel _aViewModel = new AViewModel();
private BViewModel _bViewModel = new AViewModel();
```

My XAML binds a DataControl to

```
private ViewModelBase _currentView {get; set;}
    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentView;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
```

And decides which view to display based on DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AViewModel}">
    <vw:AView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BViewModel}">
    <vw:BView />
</DataTemplate>
```

All this works fine but I'm not sure how to persist data between View changes.  Say for example that AViewModel contains a string called "Test" and has a two way binding in AView.  By changing view using CurrentView = _bviewmodel then my data won't persist when I change back to _aviewmodel - What's the best way to make sure any data stays between view changes as opposed to creating a new blank viewmodel each time.
I have to get _currentView to _aViewModel and then back to _currentView

Comment: Since you are not disposing `AViewModel`, and binding to a string called `Test` with a two-way binding, the data should be persisted already. Perhaps add a breakpoint to the `set` method of `AViewModel.Test` and make sure the value is actually getting set. Also add a breakpoint where you change `CurrentView` and make sure that `AViewModel.Test` is still set.

Comment: agree with rachel,  unless your _aViewModel and _bViewModel are going out of scope the data will remain in memory.

Comment: The value is still there when I add a breakpoint in AViewmodel (Set Test) but is not passed back to CurrentView in the ViewModelBase - I can get the value to ViewModelBase by a Mediator firing the value back but this is again lossed the next time I set "currentView" - I presume I'm creating a new view model everytime but not sure how to simply pass a reference instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data should be persistent. Make sure that you don't create new ViewModels every time you change the CurrentView.

Answer (score 1):

Should have posted my AView xaml - Inside it was

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:AViewModel></vm:AViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

So it appears I was stupidly creating a new ViewModel inside the Xaml everytime I changed the view.  Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction. I deleted this from the Xaml and all is working fine now.

Comment: I've migrated to creating the Views from my ViewModels using DataTemplates but everytime I changed the current view model, the parameterless constructor of that view model would be called. I didn't realize it was because I was setting the DataContext of my views like you pointed out. This is the answer I've been looking for all over stack overflow!